# Error while JSON decoding: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "cast", intValue: nil)

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, urlsession

While trying to decode JSON, I ran into an error:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
> Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "cast",
> intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
> debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "cast", intValue: nil) ("cast").",
> underlyingError: nil))

What is strange, it does not always appear, I can open `MovieDetailsView` several times without errors, but more often it occurs. What could be the problem?

**Data model:**

```
struct MovieCreditResponse: Codable {
    let cast: [MovieCast]
}

struct MovieCast: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let character: String
    let name: String
    let profilePath: String?
}
```

**Here I fetch data:**

```
class TMDbApi {
    //...

    func getMovieCredits(movieID: String, completion:@escaping (MovieCreditResponse) -> ()){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(movieID)/credits?api_key=<api_key>") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let movies = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MovieCreditResponse.self, from: data!) //ERROR IS HERE
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(movies)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

**MovieDetailsView:**

```
struct MovieDetailsView: View {
    var movie: Movie
    
    @State var casts: [MovieCast] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            MoviePosterView(posterPath: movie.posterPath!)
            List{
                ForEach(casts){ cast in
                    Text(cast.name)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear{
            TMDbApi().getMovieCredits(movieID: movie.id.uuidString){ data in
                self.casts = data.cast
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var movies: [Movie] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(movies) { movie in
                    NavigationLink(destination: MovieDetailsView(movie: movie)){
                        //...
                    }
                }
            }.onAppear(){
                TMDbApi().getMovies{ data in
                    self.movies = data.results
                }
                //...
            }
            .navigationTitle("Movies App")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess, the response you're getting doesn't always include the `cast` value, and since you're force-trying (which you shouldn't, you should handle the error instead), your app is crashing. Have you tried looking at the response you're getting when the decoding fails?

Comment: Also you should re-generate your API key since you've already pasted it here.

Comment: Why not check out the [documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I read the documentation [documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-credits). In my opinion I do everything according to it, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Yes my bad, I missed the last part of your url so I checked the wrong endpoint. I would suggest printing the data using `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` to see what you really get

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I get this response while an error: `\"success\":false,\"status_code\":34,\"status_message\":\"The resource you requested could not be found.\"` Also I checked the URL that I am using, everything is fine with it, it is the same as in the case when there is no error, correct. Very strange

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, yes it turns out i get an error

Comment: Server might have limitation and bugs. You shouldn't force unwrap (use `!`), just manage the error case.

Comment: @Larme Sometimes I wait for 10 seconds and do not receive data, and sometimes I can open two DetailsViews with an interval of 1-2 seconds and everything is ok, in any case it does not seem that the error message says about limits

Comment: Could you check log the URLs when that's happening and check later that it's the same that's working? If that's the case, you can check on that API forums. Also, might want to hide your API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what caused the error. I used `UUID` type instead of `Int` for `id` property in the movie model (this is the id I used in the URL to query movie casts). Therefore, in my request, the movie ID was of the form "F77A9A5D-1D89-4740-9B0D-CB04E75041C5" and not "278". Interestingly, sometimes this did not cause errors, which confused me (I still do not know why this sometimes worked)

So, I replaced

```
struct Movie: Identifiable, Codable{
    let id = UUID()
    //...
}
```

with

```
struct Movie: Identifiable, Codable{
    let id: Int
    //...
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me find a solution

Comment: To help you with this in the future, you can paste your json [here](https://app.quicktype.io/) and it will generate the correct structs and decoding code. Also, adding some (example) json to your question can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If your response might contain an error (errors do happen!), your app should be aware and handle it.

```swift
struct MovieCreditResponse: Codable {
    let success : Bool
    let status_code : Int
    let status_message : String?
    let cast: [MovieCast]?
}
```

then when you get your response, check for success and have your app handle errors:

```swift
do {
    guard let d = data else { 
        // handle null data error 
    }
    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(MovieCreditResponse.self, from: d) 
    if responseObject.success {
        guard let cast = responseObject.cast as? [MovieCast] else {
            // handle error of null cast here
        }
        // this is the happy path: do your thing
    } else {
        if let errorMessage = responseObject.status_message {
            // handle the case of an identified error
            handleError(errorMessage)
        } else {
            // handle the case where something went wrong and you don't know what
        }
    }
} catch {
    // handle decoding error here
}
```

Comment: This answer is based on an incorrect assumption, that cast might sometimes be missing,  when the issue is that it is a completely different message that is returned due to an error. Your first option might work but will hide the actual error and the second will fail the same way as the current code does.

Comment: Oh that's an excellent point, I wrote this before seeing the raw JSON, which was "below the fold."